# Extract data which is inside square brackets and separated by comma

Tags: awk, command-line

I have data like:

```
['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom2/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom3/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom4/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom5/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom6/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom7/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom8/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom9/']
```

I want each value without quote one per line so that I can pipe it to another command, like:

```
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/
....
```

`awk -F'[][]' '{print $2}'` removes the square brackets. I am not understanding how to proceed further.

Comment: `awk -F"'" '{ for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) print $i }'` seems to be a good solution for me.

Comment: Can you install a new software, like [jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/)? It would be useful to parse this JSON.

Comment: @A.L I have jq installed. Any solution is welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just remove the leading `['`, trailing `']` and replace all `', '` with a newline, and delete a `[]` or `@as []` line which I see `gsettings` using to represent empty lists of strings (where the `@as` prefix specifies that the array is an `a`rray of `s`trings).

```
gsettings get some-path some-array-key... |
  sed "/^@as \[\]\$/d
       /^\[\]\$/d
       s/^\['//
       s/'\]\$//
       s/', '/\\
/g"
```

With GNU `sed`, the newline in the replacement in the last `s` command above can be expressed as `\n` instead of `\` followed by a literal newline.

If it weren't for the `'...'` instead of `"..."` and that `@as` prefix for empty lists, that would be a valid JSON array, so you could also do:

```
gsettings get some-path some-array-key |
  sed "y/'/\"/; s/^@as //" |
  jq -r '.[]'
```

Note that none of those work for arbitrary arrays of strings as they don't  account for the escaping that can be done by `gsettings` as evidenced by:

```
$ gsettings list-recursively  | grep '\\'
org.freedesktop.ibus.panel.emoji favorites ['\u200b']
org.gnome.evolution.shell filename-illegal-chars "'\"&`();|<>$%{}!"
```

(where we can even see it switching to `"..."` in the last case where the string value contains a `'`, making it a proper JSON string in that case).

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.seahorse last-search-text $'\1\xa\U10FFFF\'\"\\'
$ gsettings get org.gnome.seahorse last-search-text
"\u0001\n\U0010ffff'\"\\"
```

The format seems to be the one described at https://developer-old.gnome.org/glib/stable/gvariant-text.html

The `JSON:PP` `perl` module supports JSON strings using single quote delimiters, so you could use it to extract and decode any single-quoted or double-quoted string in any GVariant object with something like:

```
gsettings any-path any-key |
  perl -C -MJSON::PP -lne '
    BEGIN{
      $j = JSON::PP->new->allow_singlequote
    }
    print $j->decode($_) for
      /'\''(?:\\.|[^\\'\''])*'\''|"(?:\\.|[^\\"])*"/g'
```

Where the regexp finds pairs of `'...'` or `"..."` (allowing for escaped quotes or backslashes inside), that are passed to the JSON decoder. Ignoring the `b'...'`, `b"..."` bytestrings on which JSON:PP would choke as AFAICT, `gsettings` outputs them as `[byte 0xHH, 0xHH...]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU grep for `-o` and assuming your quoted strings don't contain any of the chars `][ ,'` or newline:

```
$ grep -Eo "[^][ ,']+" file
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom2/
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom3/
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom4/
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom5/
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom6/
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom7/
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom8/
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom9/
```

otherwise using any awk and allowing for any chars except `'` or newline in the quoted strings:

```
$ awk -F"'" '{for (i=2; i<NF; i+=2) print $i}' file
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom2/
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom3/
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom4/
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom5/
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom6/
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom7/
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom8/
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom9/
```

Comment: In the [*GVariant Text Format*](https://developer-old.gnome.org/glib/stable/gvariant-text.html) output by `gsettings`, in strings newline is encoded as `\n`. It's not the only character that's encoded with some form of backslash escape, see my answer for details.